# Invalid use of scope operator in C++

Tags: java, c++, unordered-map

I'm trying to manually port some Java into C++.

The Java:

```
public Class Item {
    public String storage = "";
    public Item(String s, int tag) { storage = s; }
    ...
}

public class ProcessItems {
    Hashtable groups = new Hashtable();
    void save(Item w) { groups.put(w.storage, w); }
}
```

My C++:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<unordered_map>
#include<string>


class Item {
    public:
        std::string storage;
        Item(std::string s, int tag) { storage = s; }
        ...
}

class ProcessItems {
    public:
        std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> *groups = new std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>();
        void save(Item w) { groups.insert(w::storage, w); }
        ...
}
```

Compiling in C++ 11 I get the following error:

```
error: invalid use of ‘::’
    string, std::string> *words = new std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>();
                                                                         ^
```

Where'd I go wrong?

Comment: I strongly suggest getting rid of the pointer. It's far more common and less work to have `std::unordered_map<...> groups;` and leave it at that. For example, I'll bet you don't have a [destructor, copy constructor, and assignment operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) to avoid the pointer being invalid or the map leaked. It's much easier to have a plain object that gets destroyed when the class does and gets copied when the class does.

Comment: Having pointers to containers (vectors, maps, etc) is an anti-pattern. A common reason is that you want to have a `nullptr` if there are no elements, but in that case you should have an empty container.

Comment: As a straight port, this will work, but once you get it working you'll want to un-pointer all of your code, as everyone else has said. It prevents null pointer issues and makes your data more spatially local.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: [why not?](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/authentication.html)

Comment: There needs to be `;` at the end of each class definition.    In any event, avoid making members pointers, which also means don't create objects using operator `new`.  C++ differs substantially from Java in this regard - writing as you would in Java is VERY poor practice in C++.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Java both member resolution and scope resolution are done with operator dot `.`, while in C++ these operators are different:

- Use `::` to access a member of a namespace or a static member of a class
- Use `.` to access a member of an instance represented by reference or by value
- Use `->` to access a member of an instance represented by pointer

Since `storage` is an instance member of `Item`, use

```
groups.insert(w.storage, w);
```

Note that you would be better off if you pass `w` by constant reference:

```
void save(const Item& w) { groups.insert(w::storage, w); }
```

You also need to change `groups` from a pointer to an object, and fix its type to match what you plan to put into the map:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string,Item> groups;
```

Unlike Java, C++ will initialize `groups` to a valid object without an explicit call to the default constructor.

Comment: Yes, looks like you're right, but the compiler is not even getting to that line. It's failing on the line above it.

Comment: @OrdinaryHuman Please see the edit. You should do the same thing to `words` as to `groups`

Comment: std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> groups; do you really want to Insert string values, or values of type Item?

Comment: @OrdinaryHuman, I can reproduce that error on GCC 4.8, but I get a different error first: `Item` has no semicolon at the end of the class definition. Fixing that makes this confusing error go away.

Comment: @harandk You are right, OP needs to specify the correct type in order for this to compile.